# How to remove .pdf restrictions from PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I've been using qpdf to remove `.pdf` restrictions, this can be used throught php like this:

```
shell_exec('qpdf --decrypt "'.$pdfName.'" unlocked.pdf');
```

This works well on localhost, but it's impossible to execute on a shared web hosting for security reasons.

So I'm looking for another way to make this work without shell commands.

Is there any solution on PHP or JavaScript languages?

**EDIT**:

The pdf that I'm testing is not blocked by password, all I know is that I can't copy text from it but after applying that "qpdf --decrypt.." command, I can do it.

Comment: Get hosting that support shelling out.

Comment: @ceejayoz They told us to get a VPS and that's not a way for now.

Comment: Well, that'd be my advice as well. You can get one for $2-5/month in a variety of places.

Comment: @ceejayoz not in Chile

Comment: As long as you've got access to a credit/debit card, something like https://www.digitalocean.com/ should still work in Chile I'd think.

Comment: I know but we need a server in Santiago, Chile.

Comment: If performance is the concern there, you could consider something like CloudFlare. They have a Chilean location: https://blog.cloudflare.com/bienvenido-a-chile-cloudflares-24th-data-center-now-live/

Comment: Which kind of "restrictions" do you try to remove? Is it only about edit restrictions or also about a password to read that document?

Comment: @NicoHaase the same than qpdf does with that command I've posted

Comment: Make sure you use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) before passing to `shell_exec` though.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following repositories in GitHub [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk)

Example PHP code:

```
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

$pdf = new Pdf('/path/my.pdf');

$pdf->allow('AllFeatures')      // Change permissions
    ->flatten()                 // Merge form data into document (doesn't work well with UTF-8!)
    ->compress($value)          // Compress/Uncompress
    ->keepId('first')           // Keep first/last Id of combined files
    ->dropXfa()                 // Drop newer XFA form from PDF
    ->dropXmp()                 // Drop newer XMP data from PDF
    ->needAppearances()         // Make clients create appearance for form fields
    ->setPassword($pw)          // Set owner password
    ->setUserPassword($pw)      // Set user password
    ->passwordEncryption(128)   // Set password encryption strength
    ->saveAs('new.pdf');
```

Comment: I'm not using composer, how should I include the library on my .php file?

Comment: You can download the library directly from https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk/archive/0.5.0.zip and use it.

Comment: I've downloaded the lib and now I'm testing your code but it throws: Fatal error: Class 'mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\php\libs\php-pdftk-0.5.0\ArteeCode.php on line 5

Comment: can you explain how to use that library? I'm using PHP with XAMPP. I'm not using composer or laravel. I've downloaded the library but the code you posted throws that error.

Comment: You're going to have the same problem with `mikehaertl/php-pdftk`, as I believe it needs `PDFtk` to be installed. There is no pure play PHP or JavaScript solution that I'm aware of. You _could_ try a third party solution where you farm out the work, but that will come at a price.

Answer (score -2):

All this what you need is possible with Mozilla's PDF Reader written in JavaScript (PDF.js). You can show all PDFs without restrictions on a shared web hosting. I have tested it now for text copy, document print and other restrictions - you can do all this without restrictions.

Only for document reading password you will need a passord and I hope that you understand that deleting of this passord is not possible with any other software if the password is strong enough. You can also open all documents online with password for opening (if it has one), but all other restrictions will be skipped. I have tested it with [256-bit of key length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size) from owner and user passwords.

### [Online DEMO](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

And if somebody does not understand what the QPDF library from OP (Original Poster) does I have found following information about this QPDF library:

> A secured PDF file has two types of passwords: OWNER and USER.
>   The OWNER password is used to enforce permissions.
>   The USER password is used to open the pdf file.
>   ...
>   You can decrypt it if it's secured with a USER password as well, but you need to know the password.
>
> [Source](https://github.com/wilfredwee/wilfred-TILs/blob/master/command-line-pdf/decrypting-a-pdf-file-without-owner-password-on-the-command-line.md)

With this library you **do not need** to write **explicit** some code to remove the PDF restrictions. It removes the restrictions (for owner password) by the reading from document **automatically**. And in the case if the user password (for opening the PDF file) is setted then it shows by the reading from document the input dialogue for this password **automatically**.

**Conclusion:** PDF.js library and QPDF library from OP do the same in the case of restrictions.

### How to start

Just open the **home site** link below and go to the **Getting Started** site (you will find this possibility in the top of the page) – you will find there all instructions for the starting.

**PDF.js** is an **[open source project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)** (GitHub link).

On this **[home site](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)** you will find:

- Getting Started information
- Examples (a lot of code examples)
- FAQ (answers)
- API description

**Useful links:**

- **[Issue Reporting Guide](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)**
- **[Code Contribution Guide](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Contributing)**
- **[Good Beginner Bugs](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues?direction=desc&labels=5-good-beginner-bug&page=1&sort=created&state=open)**
- **[Exended projects with PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/projects)**
- **[QPDF-manual](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html)**

Comment: Can you explain further how all that really solves the problem? To me, this looks like a link-only answer

Comment: @NicoHaase, it is not a link-only answer in this case because it is big library and I can not put here all the source code of it. I have in my question enough information about it and it is official presentation pages from Mozilla. I other case if you need any other information about it please write me about it and I will add the info to my answer.

Comment: @Bharata it seems a nice library but you're not telling to me where to start or where's the example who removes the pdf restrictions. Also I've never talked about passwords.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo, I do not understand why I get from you the downvote for the best solution for you? Do you think that so much work is no more valuable as one downvote? It is really unfair! Or maybe did you do the mistake by voting? Please, consider again your voting. I wrote now **explicit for you** in my answer all the information which you want.

Comment: You're telling to me where to start exploring the library, but you have not shown me even a single line of code that contains what I need or even a little part of it. It's 50% about passwords and 50% libs links/references.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo,  the PDF which you are testing is blocked by OWNER password. The restrictions (for example for copy text) are setted with this password. **[Here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/852787)** you can read on official Adobe site what are  owner and user passwords.

Comment: the thing is with "qpdf --decrypt.." command I don't need to know the password to decrypt the pdf file and my question is about a way to do the same than that shell command.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo, all the code examples are **[here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/)**. And I wrote this even in the first version of my answer. This JS library do the same like your shell command automatically. If you will get some PDF with a user password you will not able to open this PDF without the password with your shell command too. TRY IT! And what is about the downvote? Do you think that so much work is no more valuable as one downvote?

Comment: nice examples, can you indicate where's the example who decrypt the pdf file and then saves it? Because that's what "qpdf --decrypt.." command does and that's what I've said that I need. I'm not interested on view the pdf on the navigator.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo, **[Here is the link](https://www.pdfhost.net/index.php?Action=DownloadFile&id=a99f6c913f9709649282c104bdbd6026)** to very simple one page PDF file with password "984.665.640.564.039.457.584.007.913.129.639.936.115.792.089.237.316.195.423.570.985.008.687.907.853.269" (without " characters). I have uploaded it for you. Try to open this file with your shell command. You will not able to do it without this password. And if you are not interested on view the PDF on the navigator then why I get this information now (after 5 days later)? Do you want only server side solution?

Comment: ...password. I don't know why you've assumed such a thing.